# Numpy - Average distance between columns

Tags: python, numpy

**I have a 2D array, and I want to calculate the average distance between each column taking into account every row.**

For example, if I had the 2D array:

```
2  2  3
4  2  5
1  5  2
```

I want to compute the average distance between columns 1 and 2 across all rows, 1 and 3 across all rows, and 2 and 3 across all rows.

The average distance across columns 1 and 2 would be `( |2-2| + |4-2| + |1-5| ) / 3`, which equals 2.

Is there a numpy function that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[2,2,3],[4,2,5],[1,5,2]])

def calc(cols):
    return np.mean(np.abs(np.diff(x[:, cols])))

print(calc([0,1]))
```

Out:

```
2.0
```

Also consider:

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.combinations(range(x.shape[1]), 2)))  # outer list because using py3
```

Out:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want!  Is there a way to run `calc` for every possible permutation of columns, instead of specifying the columns manually?

Comment: Either prepare a for-loop (eliminating symmetries) or use itertools to prepare all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest doing this instead:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
m, n = in_arr.shape
pdist(in_arr.T, 'cityblock') / m

Out: array([ 2.        ,  1.        ,  2.33333333])
```

If you want to know which distance relates to which pair, use:

```
np.stack(np.triu_indices(n, 1))  

Out: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

This should be much faster than using `for` loops or `itertools`